# Implicit Style Within Container

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-style, implicit-style

I want to apply `Padding="0"` to each `Label` on the left sidebar (the first `StackPanel`) so that it left-aligns with each `TextBox` (and other controls).

How can I define an implicit style in `<ApplicationResources>` which only applies to elements within a specific container?

Alternatives:

1. Use `x:Key="sidebarLabel"`.  However, this option seems redundant for the many labels in the sidebar of my actual application.
2. Add `Padding=0` to each `Label` in the sidebar.  This is essentially the same as the previous alternative.
3. Move the implicit style into `<StackPanel.Resources>`.  However, I want to keep the styles (in `App.xaml`) separate from the XAML (in `MainWindow.xaml`).

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
        <GroupBox Header="New User">
            <StackPanel>
                <Label>First Name:</Label>
                <TextBox/>
                <Label>Last Name:</Label>
                <TextBox/>
            </StackPanel>
        </GroupBox>
    </StackPanel>
    <GroupBox Grid.Column="1" Header="Main">
        <StackPanel>
            <Label>I want default padding here</Label>
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `Style.Resources` in app.xaml like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

this sets all `Label.Style`, that are used inside a `StackPanel`. If you like to provide this behaviour only to labels in specific `StackPanels` you can use a `x:Key` like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="StackPanel" x:Key="LabelStyledPanel">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

then all `StackPanels` using `StaticResource LabelStyledPanel` use the label style.