# How to get list of Controls of a type from whole Window?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have WPF MVVM application where I have several ItemsControls on several levels looking like:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=cb_Letter, Path=SelectedItem.Words2}" Name="ICWords2">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid >
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding .}" />
                                <TextBox Grid.Column="1"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
```

and I want to controll all items by command executed from:

```
<Button Grid.Column="4" Name="btn_Check" Command="CMDS:Commands.Check"></Button>
```

In command:

```
var parrents = CollectionOfAll<ItemsControl>(Window);
        foreach (var items in parrents)
        {
            foreach (var item in items.Items)
            {
                var child = FindChild<Grid>((UIElement)items.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item));
                Label lb = child.Children.OfType<Label>().First();
                TextBox tb = child.Children.OfType<TextBox>().First();
                tb.BorderBrush = lb.Content.ToString() == tb.Text.ToString() ? Brushes.Green : Brushes.Red;
            }
        }
```

But I am brand new to WPF and cant figure out how to get all childs of childs of childs .... and so on of type

so TODO is:

```
private List<T> CollectionOfAll<T>(...){...}
```

Why am I doing it like this?
It is application for injured kids to learn how to write on pc, so in label is a character or string and they have to try write it to textbox on the right of that label and then I have to chek if it is correct

Comment: I [don't think you really need that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is it you are trying to achieve? There are better solutions in WPF than manually parsing controls, like binding and data templating.

Comment: Is it what you looking for [Implicit Style Within Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45178606/implicit-style-within-container)

Comment: @CorentinPane Cause I want to make control of em, if they are correctly filled.. It  is application for injured kids to learn how to write on pc :D so in label is a character or string and they have to try write it to textbox on the left of that label and then i have to chek if it is correct

Comment: @Rekshino no. :/

Answer (score 0):

**Manually parsing controls in a WPF application is an antipattern.**

WPF provides better ways to achieve what you need through [binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview) and [templating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/fundamentals/styles-templates-overview).

You can use a `Style` on each `TextBox` to have WPF automatically change the `BorderBrush` property depending on the equality result between the `Text` property and the `DataContext` value (which seems to be a of type `string` in your case).

```xml
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <local:EqualityConverter x:Key="EqualityConverter"/>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding .}" />
                <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Grid.Column="1">
                    <TextBox.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" /> <!-- Default color -->
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Value="true">
                                    <DataTrigger.Binding>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource EqualityConverter}">
                                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=Self}" Path="Text"/>
                                            <Binding Path="."/>
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </DataTrigger.Binding>
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green" /> <!-- Color when values are equal -->
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBox.Style>
                </TextBox>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

You need to define an additional piece of code (a `Converter`):

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Returns true if all passed values are equal.
/// </summary>
public class EqualityConverter : IMultiValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => values.All(v => v.Equals(values[0]));

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

**Fixing the issue in a WPF-oriented way**

An even better way to achieve what you want is to define a correct view model from the start:

```cs
public class QuestionViewModel {
    public string RequiredText { get; set; }
    public string InputText{ get; set; }
    public bool IsCorrect => RequiredText.Equals(InputText);
}
```

(It should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` but for simplicity I haven't shown that)

And you would bind your `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` to a collection of `QuestionViewModel` instead of a collection of `string`:

```xml
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Questions}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding RequiredText}" />
                <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding InputText}">
                    <TextBox.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsCorrect}"  Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBox.Style>
                </TextBox>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

You should have a look at the MVVM pattern probably.

Comment: Well, pretty cool, but how can I find out number of misstakes?